# Change locale name in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a multilingual Rails app where I would like to include also a Czech locale. My problem is, that locale in Rails for Czech is `cs` while a more common abbreviation for Czech is `cz`. My client requires their locale (which is used in URI) to be `cz`. I can't use `cz` right away because it throws an error about unkown locale.

My question therefore is, how can I change the abbreviation of a locale to a desired one?

I'm using Rails 4 with i18n gem.

Comment: You you have a `cz.yml` file in your locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

1. For `application.rb`:

> ```
> # ...
> config.i18n.available_locales = %w(en cz)
> # ...
> ```

2. Ensure you have `config/locales/cz.yml`

Then, in console:

```
I18n.locale = :cz
=> :cz
I18n.t(:a)
=> "b"
```

Comment: Awesome, problem was probably in the missing config in application.rb, I had cz.yml before. Thank you.